# html5 client-side form validation and language

Tags: html, validation, internationalization

Opera already supports several HTML5 form validation attributes such as required, pattern, etc...
So when I leave a required field empty and submit it an error message appears next to the field.
This is great but I didn't find any way to change the default message, also to change the language of the error message (I tried the lang attribute).

how should this work?
(I didn't find anything about it in the specification)

thx, 
Viktor

Comment: if i download the japanese version of opera, the message is Japanese but there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: you are right Victor, this is a total screw up; language of message should depend on user selection, not some arbitrary, browser based setting - say I use friend's browser set to Japanese, but navigate English website and do not speak Japanese one bit; additional screw up is lack of influence over text of message; obviously people designing that forgot, what web design is all about.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to change it, or even style it, at present.  The idea is that the user gets a more consistent interface (across all websites) and things which developers often don't think about, such as accessibility and internationalization, are taken care of by the browser.  However, the ability to customize has been the subject of some debate.

You might be able to implement your own handler, [have a look at what this guy's done to replace the standard messages](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/combine/html5-form/index.html).